# : assert(map['apiKey'] != null, "'apiKey' cannot be null."),

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

i'm trying to develop an app on Android studio, with firebase tools. Despite i have a file in the lib firebase_options (created with flutterfire configure), it always give me error:
`
E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/firebase_options.dart': Failed assertion: line 61 pos 16: 'map['apiKey'] != null': 'apiKey' cannot be null.
#0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:51:61)
#1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:40:5)
#2      new FirebaseOptions.fromMap (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/firebase_options.dart:61:16)
#3      MethodChannelFirebase._initializeFirebaseAppFromMap (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:45:23)
#4      ListMixin.forEach (dart:collection/list.dart:86:13)
#5      MethodChannelFirebase._initializeCore (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:35:10)

#6      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:73:7)

#7      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:40:31)

#8      main (package:my_firstapp/main.dart:13:3)

`
my main.dart is :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_firstapp/locator.dart';
import 'package:my_firstapp/models/user_model.dart';
import 'package:my_firstapp/screens/wrapper.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:my_firstapp/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';


void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );  
 setupServices();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<UserModel>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
      initialData: null,
      child: MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Color(0xff5FA55A),
          secondaryHeaderColor: Color(0xff5FA55A),
        ),
        home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What can i do, i'm stuck on this problem. Please help me

Comment: I think you didn't initialize api key
Please look at this solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71171586/8888756)

Comment: i've already tryied with no success. Any other idea?

Comment: try this : from UserModel to UserModel?

Comment: thanks, where do i have to add it?

Answer (score 0):

The API key is missing from the firebase_options file.  Open the firebase_options file, check line 61 and also Ctrl+f 'apiKey' to find other mentions in the file where it's missing.

To find the API key:

1. The Android app Api key can be found in the google-services.json file.
2. The ios app Api key can be found in the GoogleService-Info.plist
3. For the web app, go to the firebase console, select project settings from the menu.

Comment: Already tryied, doesn't work for me

Comment: i've tryied, same result...actually i'm not understanding why it goes through "firebase_core_platform_interface/src/firebase_options.dart" and not via " lib\firebase_options.dart"

Comment: I need more info. What does the setupServices() function inside main do? could you provide a code snippet. In the meantime, to get more context of the error, try $ flutter run --verbose

Comment: on  lutter run --verbose i get only the same error above...See my setupService below as snippet